# yasnippet does not load automatically when .html file is loaded

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

yasnipped has been installed on emacs using elpa/melpa package system.

I can confirm it's in ~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20160104.129

When I load an .html file there's no yasnippet menu, as expected, please advise. I did not add anything extra to .emacs

Comment: yasnippets must be installed into the appropriate mode directory to be loaded for this mode. Where is your yasnippets directory? For me html yasnippets are stored in `~/.emacs.d/yasnippets/html-mode`

Comment: Thanks. They are where elpa put them - in ~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-version-number/snippets/html-mode. What I did was renamed yasnippet-version-number to yasnippet. Then I loaded that directory in .emacs and included require 'yasnippet. Now it loads automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution might cause you some problems when it comes to updating the elpa yasnippet package. Normally not a good idea to rename the package directories.

There are a couple of things you probably should try first.

1. When you have opened an html file, try running

   M-x yas-minor-mode

If this works, then all you need to do is add a call to yas-minor-mode in the startup hook for html-mode.

2. Alternatively, you can try executing

   M-x yas-global-mode

If this works, then all you need to do is put a call to

```
(yas-global-mode)
```

in your init.el file

3. If this does not work, check the value of the variables `yas-snippets-dirs` and `yas-installed-snippets-dirs`. The former is the normal yas variable which lists the directories to search for snippets. The latter is a variable which should contain the path to the top level snippets directory in the elpa package. The former would normally contain something like

   "~/.emacs.d/snippets" yas-installed-snippets-dires

If the `yas-installed-snippets-dirs` variable exists and looks correct, you could try putting something like

```
(yas/load-directory yas-installed-snippets-dirs)
```

in your init.el file after you have done the require for yasnippets